# How to change a single menu item text size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this piece of code in my menu.xml, which is inside a navigation view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item
            android:title="Blue"
            android:id="@+id/blue">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/red"
                    android:title="Red"
                    />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
           <item
                android:id="@+id/green"
                android:title="Green" />
           <item
                android:id="@+id/yellow"
                android:title="Yellow"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

I want to change only the blue item text size. How can I do that??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create your menu, you can change the size of your text like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
    awesome.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.blue)
        {
            SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
            int end = spanString.length();
            spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            item.setTitle(spanString);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```